# How can I print a heading before a list, based on the contents of the list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I have a block for an array, and for each value I either print or don't print something based on some criteria.

```
<% @friends.each do |friend| %>
  <% if friend.status.best = true %>
    <%= friend.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If at least one value is printed, I want a heading, like so:

```
BEST FRIENDS
  friend1
  friend2
  etc
```

But if no values end up being printed, I don't want any heading at all.

---

Here's what I tried:

If I set some variable `@v` within the block conditional,

```
  <% if friend.status.best = true %>
    <%= friend.name %>
    <% @v = true %>
  <% end %>
```

I could then use an `if @v` conditional to print a heading, but the problem is that the heading should be printed BEFORE the block.

It occurred to me to use an `if @v` conditional to fill in the heading with javascript, but that sometimes isn't instantaneous, and I want the heading to be there right away.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: first of all your `if` condition is not proper. change it to `if friend.status.best == true` or just simply use `if friend.status.best`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<% skip_header = false

@friends.each do |friend|
  if friend.status.best == true
    unless skip_header
      concat 'BEST FRIENDS'
      skip_header = true
    end
    concat friend.name
  end
end %>
```

Comment: in if condition are you checking for `true` or assigning `true`? to check `==` is required or you can simply use `if friend.status.best`

Comment: @GaganGami Thanks. Corrected. I actually copied code from OP.

Comment: This isn't a very good idea. You have assignment in the views, you use concat (which is not required at all unless you want to return the data in block as a return value from a method) and the code doesn't seem to be a good fit for a view as it contains a lot of business logic/assignments.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti  `concat` is alias to `<%=` ruby tag in view. I've just replaced the `<%=` tag to `concat` from OP. And I don't think there's a lot business logic here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Enumerable#any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) to quickly determine if there is at lest one best friend.

```
<% if @friends.any? { |friend| friend.status.best } %>
  # The header
<% end %>
```

Also note that you have an error in your code. You are assigning the value true to the attribute best:

```
<% if friend.status.best = true %>
  <%= friend.name %>
<% end %>
```

This will cause the loop to always return true and print out the name. What you want to do is to replace `=` with `==`

```
<% if friend.status.best == true %>
  <%= friend.name %>
<% end %>
```

or simply

```
<% if friend.status.best %>
  <%= friend.name %>
<% end %>
```

Back to the original problem, the approach of `#any?` is a little bit inefficient if the number of items is large, as you need to loop the collection twice. Moreover, you are iterating the entire `@friends` collection when what you really want (at least from the fragment you posted) is to show the best friends.

You may want to change the query so that `@friends` will only contains the best friends (those records where `best` is `true`). In that way you can simply check against the presence of a value in the collection.